# UICollectionViewCell background color change works in cellForItemAtIndexPath but not didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I can change my collection view cell background color in `cellforitematindexpath` but not in `didselectitematindexpath` using the code below (i only change the color in one place however). How does this happen? 
I know that `didselectitematindexpath` is being called.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    cell.label.text = @"test"
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected cell");
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [self collectionView:cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things wrong here.

1. You're using the wrong method to get the selected cell. Never call the delegate method directly, instead ask the collection view for the cell directly like this:

   CollectionViewCell *cell = [cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
2. You're modifying the cell in a place where those modifications will not persist. When you scroll and that cell gets reused, the color will get wiped out. Instead you should call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` when the cell gets selected, and have some code in `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` that checks the `selected` property of the cell and sets the color you want based on that. That way, the layout will remain consistent when you scroll and cells are reused.

Answer (score -2):

use this..

```
self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

then..

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";


RecipeViewCell *cell = (RecipeViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame-2.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];

return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (shareEnabled) {
        NSString *selectedRecipe = [recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedRecipes addObject:selectedRecipe];
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (shareEnabled) {
        NSString *deSelectedRecipe = [recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedRecipes removeObject:deSelectedRecipe];
    }
}
```